# What are some similar alternatives to using classmethod and property decorators together?

Tags: python, decorator, circular-dependency

What are some similar alternatives to using classmethod and property decorators together?

In python 3.11 and later, combining them is no longer supported per: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#classmethod

I have code like so:

```
class Bike:
  @classmethod
  @property
  def tire_type(cls) -> tire_type.Road:
    return tire_type.Road

from . import tire_type
```

tire_type import must be last because it has a cyclic dependency on the current module.
What are some options for providing the tire property in the Bike class that does not combine the two decorators?

I also want the tire_type type hint to show up correctly in vscode.

Comment: Are you asking because this has been deprecated?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am asking it

Comment: "tire_type import must be last because it has a cyclic dependency on the current module" I generally try to avoid writing `from . import x` for specifically this reason. Usually you can get away with `from .x import x`. This can cause a bit of churn during refactors, but it does prevent circular dependency between the current module and the `__init__.py` file in the package.

Comment: The dependencies come from an openapi spec. To eliminate the cycle, I would need to merge python files which is possible but would take more processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can always implement your own descriptor. Here is a bare-bones one that assumes the method you are decorating is a "getter":

```
>>> class classproperty:
...     def __init__(self, method):
...         self.method = method
...     def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
...         if cls is None:
...             cls = type(obj)
...         return self.method(cls)
...
>>> class Foo:
...     bar = 42
...     @classproperty
...     def baz(cls):
...         return cls.bar * 2
...
>>> class FooSpecial(Foo):
...     bar = 11
...
>>> Foo.baz
84
>>> FooSpecial.baz
22
```

Both `classmethod` and `property` are implemented as descriptors. You can read more about how the descriptor protocol works [in the Descriptor HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) which actually shows pure python implementations of [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) and [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods) which you can consult if you need to elaborate on the above.

Comment: Can you write this in a way that vscode type hints for for the baz property and baz returns a class?

Answer (score 1):

Some options are

1. Write a custom descriptor that uses a generic to return the wrapped type

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

class classprop(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, method: typing.Callable[..., T]):
        self.method = method
        functools.update_wrapper(self, method) # type: ignore

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None) -> T:
        if cls is None:
            cls = type(obj)
        return self.method(cls)


class Bike:
    @classprop
    def tire_type(cls) -> typing.Type[tire_type.Road]:
        return tire_type.Road

print(Bike.tire_type)
```

2. Make the method classmethod only, this keeps class access but `()` are required
3. Make it staticmethod but `()`  are required
4. Make the class a dataclass and use default_factory to return the desired class

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Bike
    tire_type: typing.Type[tire_type.Road] = dataclasses.field(
        default_factory=lambda: tire_type.Road
    )


print(Bike().tire_type)
```

Option 1 or 4 is preferred because it does not need `()` and it allows a type discriptions of the property and delayed evaluation of the property later when accessing Bike or instantiating it